# How to do a custom SQL query (or do not in child table)

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I would like to do a Quicksight dashboard from a query where it does SQL NOT IN (in other table).

However when I go to Quicksight and add a data set or edit it I dont see an option to do custom SQL. I am using RDS/Mysql.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to switch to custom SQL mode while editing existing dataset if it was created for a specific DB table.

However, you can use custom SQL by [creating a new data set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-database-data-set.html) using RDS datasource:
[image]